# Django DoesNotExist/admin/

Tags: python, django

Hi Folks this is my first encounter with django im doing the django tutorial 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial02/ and i have an error when i uncomment the lines they told me to,

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
```

and

```
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

in urls.py inside my roots folder

besides i realized that some lines are different ( i supose because i'm using a newer version of django ) like

here are some extra screenshots

```
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)), //(site)
```

to

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)), //(myProject)
```

Any django expert that can help me with this error, because i had great reviews about this amazing framework,

here are some screenshots

[Error](http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/1005/screenshot20110526at753.png),
[urls.py](http://img861.imageshack.us/img861/1005/screenshot20110526at753.png),
[settings.py](http://img857.imageshack.us/img857/1005/screenshot20110526at753.png)

Comment: Could you give us more details about the error? What is the exact message?

Comment: You shouldn't have added that initial `url`. Remove it and follow the tutorial properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without the full error message, I'm not 100% sure what DoesNotExist is referring to, but it sounds like the admin application models haven't been created. Did you add "django.contrib.admin" to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py **and** run `python manage.py syncdb` **and** restart the (development) server?

**UPDATE**:

Probably not a good idea to be using the Subversion source (1.4 *pre-alpha* mind you). I guarantee whatever change they've made to the proper admin site setup hasn't been updated in the docs. Check out 1.3--it's great, trust me.

Comment: Agreed, this is almost certainly the prob

Comment: yes i did ^^ i have the model Poll created i add django.contrib.admin to the installed_apps in settings.py and i sync.db as well

Comment: http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/1005/screenshot20110526at753.png
http://img861.imageshack.us/img861/1005/screenshot20110526at753.png
http://img857.imageshack.us/img857/1005/screenshot20110526at753.png

Comment: I am currently experiencing this problem right now, using django 1.3.1, hmm

Answer (score 11):

It's most likely to be a `django.contrib.sites` app problem. If you are running only one site you can comment this app on your `INSTALLED_APPS`

If you want to create the missing object you can do it from `python manage.py shell`:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
Site.objects.create(pk=1, domain='<your domain>', name='<your name>')
```

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the issue for me when following the 1.4 tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/

Comment: Thank you. That also help me during the 1.4 tutorial.

Comment: Worked for me too. I guess what happened was that I didn't run django-admin.py startproject as specified in the tutorial. I had simply checked out the code from my repo onto a new machine instead.

Comment: Turns out I also needed a superuser

Answer (score 0):

You should spacify a SITE_ID in settings.py, so the the site you specificed will manage other sites' content. You can check this page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-SITE_ID
it refers:

> SITE_ID: The ID, as an integer, of the current site in
>   the django_site database table. This is used so that application data
>   can hook into specific sites and a single database can manage content
>   for multiple sites.